# How can I compare a value in a list with the others but not itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to take the value of an integer in a list, and compare it to all the other integers in the list, except for itself. If they match, I want to subtract 1 from the other integer. This is the code I have:

```
for count6 in range(num_players):
    if player_pos[count6] == player_pos[count5]:
        if not player_pos[count5] is player_pos[count5]:
            player_pos[count6] -= 1
```

I've tried a few other things, but I can't seem to make it work. I was able to get it to subtract 1 from every value, but it included the original value. How can I make this work?

Comment: since you you only have one array I'd say compare the indexes, if they match, then don't. btw "not player_pos[count5] is player_pos[count5]" will always be false..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way, just loop through each index and decrement if the value is the same, but the index is not the one you're checking against:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

nums = [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5]
pos = 3

print("List before: ", nums)

for idx in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[idx] == nums[pos] and idx != pos:
        nums[idx] -= 1

print("List after : ", nums)
```

which outputs:

```
paul@local:~/Documents/src/sandbox$ ./list_chg.py
List before:  [3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5]
List after :  [3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9, 4]
paul@local:~/Documents/src/sandbox$
```

All the `5`s have been decremented by one, except for the one at `nums[3]` which is the one we wanted to leave intact.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
>>> values = [1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 8, 1, 5]
>>> for index, value in enumerate(values):
...     for later_value in values[index + 1:]:
...         if value == later_value:
...             values[index] = values[index] - 1
... 
>>> values
[0, 2, 2, 4, 3, 8, 1, 5]
```

This decrements each value by the number of times it occurs later in the list. If you want to decrement each value by the number of times it appears EARLIER in the list, you could reverse the list first and then re-reverse it after.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about "but included the original value" means, i'm trying to use the following code, hope this is what you want :

```
>>> num_players = 4
>>> player_pos = [3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> count5 = 2
>>> for count6 in range(num_players):
    if player_pos[count6] <> player_pos[count5]:
        player_pos[count6] -= 1


>>> player_pos
[2, 3, 5, 5]
```